# Is it possible to retrieve message history from HipChat via XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, hipchat

I am building a chat client that talks to HipChat's XMPP API. I would like to retrieve 1:1 message history between the user and other's on his contact list. There is a XMPP protocol for doing this, [XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html), but it appears that HipChat does not support it. It is not listed on their [HipChat XMPP Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/hipchat.xmpp/latest/), and when I try to make that call the server returns an error saying it's not supported.

Is there any way to do this via HipChat's XMPP API? I know their OAuth API supports it, but I don't want to use that.